# How to change the 'stock management' availability text on single product page based on different conditions in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I'm trying to change the `stock management` availability text on single product page based on different conditions in WooCommerce.

There are 5 situations, depending on whether 'Enable stock management at product level' is turned `on` or `off`.

1. Turned on, Quantity: 0
2. Turned on, Quantity: 2
3. Turned on, Quantity: 3+
4. Turned off, Out of stock
5. Turned off, In stock

---

I'm using

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability', 'wcs_custom_get_availability', 1, 2);
function wcs_custom_get_availability( $availability, $_product ) {
   global $product;

    // Case 3
    if ( $_product->is_in_stock() ) {
        $availability['availability'] = __('3. Turned on, Quantity: 3+', 'woocommerce');
    }

    // Case 2
    if ( $_product->is_in_stock() && $product->get_stock_quantity() <= 2 ) {
        $availability['availability'] = sprintf( __('2. Turned on, Quantity: 2', 'woocommerce');
    }

   // Case 5
    if ( $_product->is_in_stock() && $product->get_stock_quantity() <= 0 ) {
        $availability['availability'] = sprintf( __('5. Turned off, In stock', 'woocommerce'));
    }
    
    // Case 4 and 1 - out of stock
    if ( ! $_product->is_in_stock() ) {
        $availability['availability'] = __('4. Turned off, Out of stock / 1. Turned on, Quantity: 0', 'woocommerce');
    }

    return $availability;
}
```

---

But how to make it work for variable products?

For simple product it works perfect but for variable products 2 (out of 5) situations shows wrong results:

1. Turned on, Quantity: 0 [Works ok]
2. Turned on, Quantity: 2 [Wrong - shows case no.5]
3. Turned on, Quantity: 3+ [Wrong - shows case no.5]
4. Turned off, Out of stock [Works ok]
5. Turned off, In stock [Works ok]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `$product->get_stock_quantity() <= 0` than `$_product->is_in_stock()` will always be false because the stock number is below 0 or equal to 0, so there is the error in your logic.

It is also not necessary to use and mix `global $product` and `$_product`. Because `$_product` already contains the product object.

- `$product->managing_stock()` might come in handy

So you could use instead:

```php
// Change In Stock Text
function filter_woocommerce_get_availability( $availability, $product ) {       
    // Managing stock is activated
    if ( $product->managing_stock() ) {
        // Stock quantity
        $stock_quantity = $product->get_stock_quantity();
        
        // Compare
        if ( $stock_quantity <= 0 ) {
            $availability['availability'] = __('1. Turned on, Quantity: less then or equal to 0', 'woocommerce' );
        } elseif ( $stock_quantity > 0 && $stock_quantity <= 2 ) {
            $availability['availability'] = __('2. Turned on, Quantity: 1 or 2', 'woocommerce' );           
        } elseif ( $stock_quantity > 3 )  {
            $availability['availability'] = __('3. Turned on, Quantity: 3+', 'woocommerce' );
        }
    } else {
        // In stock
        if ( $product->is_in_stock() ) {
            $availability['availability'] = __('4. Turned off, In stock', 'woocommerce' );      
        } else {
            $availability['availability'] = __('5. Turned off, Out of stock', 'woocommerce' );              
        }
    }

    return $availability;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability', 'filter_woocommerce_get_availability', 10, 2 );
```